# Android Character insert to String

Tags: android, string, insert, character

How can I insert `'\n'` ( a new line) into a string, to be custom displayed on the device's screen ? The code :

```
String s3="";
for(int i=0; i<timp.size(); i++)
           {
s3 = s3 + sbt.get(i);
}
```

That's how I form the string . Now I would like to put `'\n'` on the `s3.charAt(55)` position . Thanks.

**PS : I Don't want to replace the character on the `s3.charAt(55)` , I just want to add the newline there .**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String yourLongString = "...A huge line of string";
String preLongStr = yourLongString.subString(0, 55);
String postLongStr =  yourLongString.subString(55);

String finalString = preLongStr + "\n" + postLongStr;
```

Comment: This is not very good as it will be very, very slow on large strings.
Much better solution is using `StringBuilder.insert(index offset, String value)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
String first = s3.substring( 0, 55 );
String second = s3.substring( 56, s3.length );
s3 = first + "\n" + second;
```

Or change your for-loop by adding this after you append to s3 (if the string just needs to break as soon as it exceeds 55 characters.)

```
if( s3.length > 55 )
  s3 += "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to edit Strings.

```
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String first = "Hello";
String second = " World";

total.append(first);
total.append("\n");
total.append(second);
```